# MultipleObjectsReturned when creating multiple objects with same name

Tags: python, django

If i create two `box objects` (with the same name and with different users), i get an `MultipleObjectsReturned at /username/slug/` `get() returned more than one Box -- it returned 2!` error.

I'v also tried filtering the box objects `box = Box.objects.filter(user=user, slug=slug)` but i get the same result.

**Model**

```
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

BOX_REGEX = '^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$'
class Box(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    box_name= models.CharField( max_length=100,
                 validators=[RegexValidator(
                                regex=BOX_REGEX,
                                message='Box must only contain Alpahnumeric characters',
                                code='invalid_box_title'
                           )],)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'slug')
```

**View**

```
def boxView(request, username=None, slug=None):

    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    box = get_object_or_404(Box, user=user, slug=slug)

    template = "pages/canvas.html"
    context = {'user' : user,'box': box,}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**url**

```
url(r'^(?P<username>[\w]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', boxView, name='box'),
```

Answer (score 0):

you have try unique together,but the unique together is what your need,

```
class Box(models.Model):
    ....

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'box_name')
```

and slug do nothing with box name,why use it?i think just remove it or keep slug same with box name is better

Comment: if unique_together = ('user', 'slug') and your still get two box, the two same object must be add before your add unique_together restrain,just delete all box object in admin and try again

Comment: and unique_together = ('user', 'slug') will let one user create two box with same box name,you pay attention to this